# Declaring list as variable

Tags: apex

I have problem with declaring list as a variable

```
 public class Accountw{ 

    string Id{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    list<contactW> con{get;set;}

 public Accountw(String id,string name,list<contactW>con con1){
     Id=id;
     Name=name;
     list<contactW> con= con1;
 }
```

I get error in the list.How to come out of that error.

Comment: do you have contact Wrapper defined as you have define Account Wrapper?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Accountw{ 

string Id{get;set;}
string Name{get;set;}
list<contactW> con{get;set;}

 public Accountw(String id,string name,list<contactW> con1){
 Id=id;
 Name=name;
 con= con1;//Observe i removed list you had appened 
}
```

You must change list con= con1; to con=con1.This would fix the issue

Comment: Hi Mohith can u give your email

Comment: Also the function declaration should not say "list<contactW>con con1" it should be "list<contactW> con1"

Comment: @ManojChandran I am not suppose to  give my personal Email Id .Please post question here and i will try best to get the answer .

Comment: I have posted a new question pls check it